# Postgresql How to use match-up table to standardize value in table

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to Postgresql so please bare with me if my questions are very elementary.

Here are the tables I am currently trying to figure out this for.

[table_name]= **order**

| order_num | order_model | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | modelA/black | 50.00 |
| 2 | modelA/white | 50.00 |
| 3 | modelB/yellow | 40.00 |
| 4 | modelB/black | 40.00 |
| 5 | modelC/red | 90.00 |
| 6 | modelC/blue | 90.00 |

[table_name]= **matchup**

| model_name | friendly_name |
| --- | --- |
| modela | Headphone |
| modelb | Speaker |
| modelc | Smartphone |

I want to create a "friendly_model_name" column in the "order" table by using the records on the "matchup" table based on the following condition

*IF the "order_model" includes the "model_name" string anywhere within its value, set the corresponding "friendlyname" as the "friendly_model_name" within the "order" table*

Trying to extract a table something like the following.

| order | order_model | friendly_model_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | modelA/black | Headphone | 50.00 |
| 2 | modelA/white | Headphone | 50.00 |
| 3 | modelB/yellow | Speaker | 40.00 |
| 4 | modelB/black | Speaker | 40.00 |
| 5 | modelC/red | Smartphone | 90.00 |
| 6 | modelC/blue | Smartphone | 90.00 |

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but it is not a **code writing service** and there are certain expectations on you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Your question seems like homework (or tutorial exercise which the same thing) so also see [How do I ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Yes it is long, read it anyway.

Comment: Then update your question to include table definition (ddl scripts),  and what SQL you have tried and the results, including full complete error messages if that is the issue. All as text - **no images**.  What have you researched, and what do you not understand?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Let me make the necessary changes with my attempts